# SignalR SqlDependency Update work but when changing page it stops working

Tags: c#, signalr

Hello and thanks for reading this.

I used this [guide](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Broadcast-Real-time-SQL-69dd9fcc#content) as my base, and I have only added Owin Login/Registration(cookie)

When I login it shows the Notification from my NotificationHub and Im able to update the database and it runs the Update right away. So everything works until you try to switch page, then the notification stop. Even if i just update the current page im on.

What can be the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace LifeChange
{
[HubName("notificationHub")]
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> Users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    private static List<User> UserList = new List<User>();

    Int16 totalNewMessages = 0;

    string UserID;

    [HubMethodName("check")]
    public Task Check(string id)
    {
        if (!Users.ToList().Exists(i => i.Value.ProfileId == id))
        {
            string profileId = id; //Context.QueryString["id"];
            string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
            var user = Users.GetOrAdd(profileId, _ => new User
            {
                ProfileId = profileId,
                ConnectionIds = connectionId
            });
            lock (user.ConnectionIds)
            {
                Groups.Add(connectionId, user.ProfileId);
            }
            return base.OnConnected();

        }
        return null;
    }

    [HubMethodName("sendNotifications")]
    public Task SendNotifications(string id)
    {
        UserID = id;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT NotificationNumber FROM [dbo].[NotificationStatus] WHERE UserID=" + UserID;

            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)

                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                dt.Load(reader);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    totalNewMessages = Int16.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["NotificationNumber"].ToString());

                }

            }

        }

        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();

        //return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages);
        return context.Clients.Client(Users.Values.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProfileId == UserID).ConnectionIds).RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages);

    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            NotificationHub nHub = new NotificationHub();
            nHub.SendNotifications(UserID);

        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: When you refresh, then that user is no longer connected. Therefore calling `context.Clients.Client(id)` on his id will fail, crash your application, restart your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong here, you should read some good basic docs about SignalR concepts first. The guide you are referring to is very poor. The main things you should check:

- hubs are created by SignalR from scratch each time a hub method is called from a client, and then destroyed, therefore for something as basic as this you should not interfere with that, which instead you do with your event handler
- because of the previous point, your `UserID` member is simply not in the right place, and it *sort of* works for you just because of wrong side effects you are generating with more mistakes (described below): do not store any state supposed to live across calls inside hubs instance members, it is not meant to survive
- you explicitly do a `new NotificationHub()` for something that has nothing to do with SignalR broadcasting, you should move the sql dependency stuff outside of the hub and do it there, while leaving hubs do their own stuff only
- when you change page your connection is lost, buy your event handler is (probably) artificially keeping a "dead" hub instance alive, and it uses it for notification, but that's simply wrong

You should review your design, starting by managing the sql dependency outside of hubs. You already know about `IHubContext`, so use that from outside hubs, and you should use hubs just for what they are for, without keeping them alive artificially when attaching them to dependency event or, even worse, creating them explicitly. You're on the road to entangled spaghetti code which is hard to reason about and understand, as you are clearly experiencing.